# mysql sql query Fetch takes much longer than Duration

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a query which returns data within 20 secs for one parameter vs over 2 mins for another parameter.
Both parameters have similar data, not a huge difference in terms of number of rows returned.

The Duration of the query is within 5 secs but the Fetch time is over 2 mins.

Can someone tell me how the Fetch time is determined? and why it would be more for certain values in where clause vs others. any ideas appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) then [edit] your question to give more details. And please tell us which DBMS you use in your question tags; the details of query planning vary dramatically between makes and versions.